# Please What is your comment or observation about the linear combination $(1,4,6) = 1(1,4,6) + 0(1,1, 2) + 0(1,3,4)?$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to find if $v = (1,4,6)$ is a linear combination of:
$$u_1 = (1,4,6),$$
$$u_2 =(1,1,2),$$
and
$$u_3 =(1,3,4).$$
And if my answer was no or yes, comment.
I got:
$(1,4,6) = 1(1,4,6) + 0(1,1,2) + 0(1,3,4)$
So, yes, $v$ is a linear combination of $u_1, u_2, \text{ and } u_3.$
But my problem is the comment. Are the vectors $u_1, u_2, \text{ and } u_3$ linearly dependent or independent? Please is there anything you notice about this linear combination that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: There are two questions here.  The first is "is $\vec v$ a linear combination of the $\vec u_i$?"  You have correctly answered that one.  The second question is "are the three vectors $\vec u_i$ linearly independent?"  That has nothing to do with $\vec v$ and requires a separate analysis.

Comment: You could observe that the solution is unique, if the vectors were dependent, there would be an infinity of solutions besides $(1,0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

Put the vectors in matrix form, row reduce and see if you can put the matrix in reduced echelon form. If you have a row of zeros, then the vectors are linearly dependent.